# Tweepy: rate-limited after not sleeping in streaming API

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm a relatively new Python programmer, and have been using Tweepy to process the Twitter stream. I was careful to put in code to pause the stream in case of being rate-limited, but it's not working at all, and as a result I've gotten banned for overloading my stream. Trying to work this out with Twitter, but meanwhile, I'd be grateful if someone could give me a pointer. The Tweepy docs aren't great and seem to be out of sync with the current release.

The relevant parts of my code are:

```
class myStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

def on_data(self, data):
    tweet = json.loads(data)
    process_tweet(tweet) # (not shown)
    return True

def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
        logger.info('420 error: pausing 60s')
        sleep(60)
        return True # continue listening
    logger.info('Error: status %s', str(status_code))
    return True # continue listening

def on_timeout(self):
    logger.info('Timeout: pausing 60s')
    sleep(60)
    return True  # continue listening


def run():
    # (stuff not shown--logging objects, config)
    # Construct the Stream instance
    auth = _get_auth(config) # (not shown)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    while True:
        try:
            twitterStream = tweepy.Stream(auth, myStreamListener(api))
            twitterStream.sample(async=True)
        except:
            logger.error('Error occurred in stream.')
            sleep(5)
            continue
```

When I run this and tail the log file, I get:

```
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
2017-10-01 08:17:48: 420 error: pausing 60s 
^C
```

So despite my trying to wait and respect the rate limits, my bot continues to hammer the API, exponentially increasing the amount of time I have to wait before it resets. I do want the bot to keep running forever (or at least until I stop it manually), so I don't want it to return False from any of these errors. (I've seen code that waits progressively longer amounts of time, but since this isn't even waiting the 60s I want, there's not much point in looking at that just yet.)

Thanks.